# How to create a file of extention .tvm

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have a code shown below

```
private string m_simview= String.Empty;
      public string SimView
      {
         get
         {
            return m_simview;
         }
         set
         {
            m_simview= value;
         }
      }

                  string viewpath = path + "views" + "\\BIMConsole\\";
```

I need to create a file whose name is value of property `string SimView` and whose type is .tvm in a specified path ie in `string viewpath`.Can anybody suggests me code to achieve this task

Comment: so you want to create a file where the name is the value of the string SimView? (and ends with a '.tvm')

Comment: @gogNavySealYes file of name with value of SimView and of type .tvm. If value of that property is test it will be test.tvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a `File` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) exposing many file system management methods for file system objects (specifically files in this case). So, something like this:

```
File.Create(Path.Combine(viewpath, SimView) + ".tvm");
```

This method *will* return something, a `FileStream`, and once done with that you should dispose of it.

Comment: Thanks this is working with a single line of code, looks like more optimized code. But can you clear that point about dispose

Comment: Some classes are disposable because they manage their own resources that must be released at some point which you should take responsibility for. These types implement the `IDisposable` interface and expose a `Dispose` method, `FileStream` is one of them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx